# PowerBI - Duplicate Entries in Query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a query on three tables. Here there is a column GUID (which is actually unique), then there is a column date/time and a column with a phone number.

Now if the same phone number calls more than once, get duplicates with always the same GUID. Can I filter this in Power BI so that the ID only appears once?

Comment: Can you show some sample data with duplicate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correct, There is an option in **Power Query Editor** to remove all duplicate rows. You can first **select your all 3 columns**- guid, date_time and phone_number. Now right click on any of the Column's header and select **Remove Duplicate** from the list as shown in the below sample image-

[image]

**This should keep only 1 rows per distinct combination considering 3 columns.**